# How to bind a progress bar to an interval?

Tags: c#, progress-bar, windows-phone-8.1, counter

I've added a determinate progress bar to my app which is an interval training app.
The timer starts for a set number of seconds then stop for a set number of seconds, then repeats this sequence for a set number of rounds, much like this kind off application:

http://www.windowsphone.com/en-ie/store/app/simple-training-timer/2f946ba9-ffd9-4f98-85a5-c67f97868ebe

This the declaration of the progress bar in my code:

```
ProgressBar  IsIndeterminate="False" x:Name="overallProgressBar" Maximum="100"  Width="200" Margin="114,214,142,288" FontWeight="Bold" Style="{StaticResource ProgressBarStyle2}"
```

And this is how I call set the progress bar to increment in the timer_tick:

```
        void myTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


                // update the textblock on the display
                // with hh, mm, ss, ms
                ms = myStopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds;

                ss = ms / 1000;
                ms = ms % 1000;

                mm = ss / 60;
                ss = ss % 60;

                hh = mm / 60;
                mm = mm % 60;

                overallProgressBar.Value = ms;


                tblDisplay.Text = hh.ToString("00") + " : " +
                                  mm.ToString("00") + " : " +
                                  ss.ToString("00") + " : " +
                                  ms.ToString("000");



                //method to trigger timer stop and start at user input intervals
                intervalTrigger(ref workTm, ref restTm);


        }
```

At the moment this code just runs the progress bar to finish after about 5 seconds which is not in sync with the rounds being input.

I'm trying to set up my progress bar to run in sequence with these actions, do anyone know how I would achieve this?

Comment: Have you looked at `Timespan`

Comment: yes I haven't shown the complete code, I'm passing in a timespan for the wrok interval and rest interval.Is there some way that I could get the progress bar to progress in sync with passage of time from the timer_tick as against the timespans that are input by the user? For example I have a workTImeSpan which signals the end of each work round.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is the `ProgressBar` supposed to be representing exactly? Your question is not very clear.

Assuming a `TimeSpan` field named `workTimeSpan` that defines the duration of the interval being measured by the `ProgressBar`, and assuming you want to display the progress within that interval:

```
void myTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    overallProgressBar.Value =
        myStopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds / workTimeSpan.TotalMilliseconds * 100;

    // update the textblock on the display
    // with hh, mm, ss, ms
    tblDisplay.Text = myStopwatch.Elapsed.ToString("hh:mm:ss.fff");

    //method to trigger timer stop and start at user input intervals
    intervalTrigger(ref workTm, ref restTm);
}
```

A better version in WPF would bind the control values to properties, but the above would work.

If the `ProgressBar` is supposed to represent something else, then please be specific about what it's supposed to represent, where that information is in your code, and how it's updated. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Sorry let me clarify a bit better, the ProgressBar is supposed to represent the completion of each interval of workTimeSpan. So when one round of WorkTimeSpan has elapsed the bar will reset and start again after the restTimeSpan.Will trial the above code and see if that works.

Comment: You'll have to reset the `Stopwatch` at the start of each new interval. But yes, based on that description the code example I've provided should work.

Comment: I added a second progress bar which is determined by the restTimeSpan, but when I run it the restProgressBar runs insync with the workPorgress bar. This isn't the desired outcome as the rest bar should pnly run after the work bar has finished. Any ideas how I could work that out? So this is how I implemented the second progress bar ` restProgressBar.Value =
                myStopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds / restTm.TotalMilliseconds * 100;`

Comment: If you want the rest interval to not happen concurrently with the work interval, then you need to not use the same `Stopwatch` instance for both, at least not at the same time. E.g. keep a flag that indicates whether you are in a work or rest interval. Then something like `workProgressBar.Value = isWork ? (myStopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds / workTm.TotalMilliseconds * 100) : 0;` and `restProgressBar.Value = isWork ? 0 : (myStopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds / restTm.TotalMilliseconds * 100);`. Of course, you would restart the `Stopwatch` at the end of each work and rest interval and toggle the flag.

Answer (score 1):

Estimate a percentage of completion for each action, and then adjust the progress bar as a function of the overall percentage of completion each time a task completes.

Generally speaking, you can't create a determinate progress bar by using timers, since you have no way of knowing how long your operations are actually going to take.